# Casting to a fixed width signed number

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am reading back a register field from a UVM RAL model. The field itself is a 14 bit signed number, but RAL has no sense of sign so I need to grab just the relevant bits and then cast them to a signed number

```
uvm_reg_data_t reg_value;
int destination;

reg_value = reg_field.get();
assign destination = signed'(14'(reg_value));
```

Is there a way to do this with one cast? I know I could define a type and then use that, but I was wondering if there was any syntax like this that would work:

```
assign destination = (14's)'(reg_value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such syntax to do this in a single cast without a `typedef`. You could also do

```
assign destination = signed'(reg_value[13:0]);
```

But I think creating a `typedef` for the field type would be best to show your intent.

Comment: As I was typing the question I realized that these registers fields already have `typedef`s that were auto-generated from my regmap generation tool. Anyway, this wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but glad to know that the syntax doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro:

```
`define conv2signed(ral_reg) \
    signed'($size(ral_reg)'(ral_reg))
```

And then:

```
assign destination = `conv2signed(reg_value);
```

**UPDATE:**

or (since uvm_reg_data_t is I think 64b) then:

```
`define conv2signed(ral_reg, reg_width) \                                                                                                                                                             
    signed'(reg_width'(ral_reg))
```

and:

```
assign destination = `conv2signed(reg_value, 14);
```

or use function...